# Putting query data from multiple table in a html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I have a database with 5 tables, 1 of them is filled with ID's. I want to link them to the other tables (the ID's are already there) so it will show the names. for example:

ask Genre: Action

It will retrieve the Film names, Director names, Genre name, Rating and 3D option.

It will show all filmnames regarding the genre as well as the ID's of the columns of those tables.

I then tried to make query (see below) that will be able to spit out the other names, but when I try to put them in a html table it will show up with a problem saying:

> Notice: Undefined index: F.Name in ../public_html/selection_lookup.php on line 53

The same for the other names in the table.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
<?php
    include ('login.php');
    $dcxn = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password) or die ("couldn't connect to server");

    mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("unable to select database:" . mysql_error());

    $selection = $_POST["GenreSel"];

    $query= "
                SELECT F.Name, D.Name, G.Genre, R.Rating, T.ThreeDeeOption
                FROM Film F, Director D, Genre G, Rating R, ThreeDee T
                WHERE F.GenreID=$selection 
                AND F.DirID = D.DirID
                AND F.GenreID = G.GenreID
                AND F.RatingID = R.RateID
                AND F.ThreeDeeID = T.ThreeDeeID
    ";


    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed:" . mysql_error());

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo'</pre>';

?>


<table border="ridge">
    <tr class="header">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Genre</td>
        <td>Rating</td>
        <td>available in 3D?</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>".$row['F.Name']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['D.Name']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['G.Genre']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['R.Rating']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['T.ThreeDeeOption']."</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
       }

    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like you need to debug your code. Set a breakpoint and see what $row has for data. I'd also not use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. I was going to say you have a sql injection problem, but it doesn't appear you're actually using the POST data. Use PDO with prepared statements. Don't stick all of your database, business logic and html in one file. And while using a table might be appropriate, consider more modern ways to present data.

Comment: @Halfstop: There is nothing wrong about tables. You should never use them for designing a layout but if there is tabular data, they are totally OK.

Comment: @ByteHamster There are issues with tables. They can be OK to use, but there are better ways to display data such as this. You CAN use a table and you CAN use something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, if you have two fields with the same name you can use aliases as follow :

```
$query= " SELECT F.Name as fname, D.Name as dname, G.Genre, R.Rating, T.ThreeDeeOption
                    FROM Film F, Director D, Genre G, Rating R, ThreeDee T
                    WHERE F.GenreID=$selection 
                        AND F.DirID = D.DirID
                        AND F.GenreID = G.GenreID
                        AND F.RatingID = R.RateID
                        AND F.ThreeDeeID = T.ThreeDeeID
                ";
```

Then you can retrieve the data this way :

```
 <?php
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['dname']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['Genre']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['Rating']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['ThreeDeeOption']."</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
       }

    ?>
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you to validate my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases in SELECT for each field, for example

```
SELECT F.Name fname, ...
```

the you will have this alias as a key

```
$row['fname']
```